# What is the substitute for update_sql() in D7?

Tags: 7, updating

I am using [update_sql()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.inc/function/update_sql/6) in hook_update of drupal .install file (D6) ?

Can **update_sql()** be used for D7 ?

Comment: No there's no Drupal 7 equivalent. You really must read the documentation and code in the function on that page. It's very obvious what the function does, and how you can replicate it in Drupal 7. Slow down a bit - you're asking a lot of questions that would be easily answered if you just took the time to read the docs properly. Learning takes patience :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not exist any longer. You need to use [Schema API function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!schema.inc/group/schemaapi/7) dedicated for what you need to be done. For example to rename field you should use [`db_change_field`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_change_field/7).